# Why do some Login Items insist on displaying at startup, despite being set to "Hide"?

Tags: macos, startup, login-items

Under *System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items*, I have a number of applications that are set to launch on system startup.

Some of these, despite being marked to "Hide" on startup, insist on showing their application windows. I have to manually close them.

***Edit:*** At first, we thought that the reason may be that some of them were also set to *Open at Login* in the Dock Right-Click Menu options (as speculated in the comments below) – but that can't be the reason.

For example, I've just added the mapped network drive `DL` below to mount on boot. Despite having checked the box *Hide*, the folder displays on startup.

[image]

Comment: Some applications have their own settings for visibility, which can conflict with these System Preference ones. Have you gone through their preferences to see whether such settings exist? I actually use the application's own settings as the primary one, and only very rarely go to the System Preferences tab that you're displaying there.

Comment: @user158589 Thanks for the suggestion. The example applications I mentioned do not have a built-in option to open on startup/login.

Comment: To happen to something like App Store is very odd. Say, when you launch App Store and its icon is in the dock – when you right-click the dock icon to display a menu, in that menu there's a sub-menu called options. Is "Open at login" ticked? When we're talking about a big proper application that goes to the dock and consists of a big proper opaque window, launching them like that definitely brings them forward and visible. I've been under the impression that in the SysPrefs window that you're showing, those rules mostly apply to sort of background applets, menu bar helpers, little things.

Comment: @user158589 Yes, these apps are set to "Open at login" in the Dock. Perhaps I should remove that option and just keep them Hidden in the Login Items, and see what happens?

Comment: There you go, that's the reason why they come forward. Untick "Open at login" for every proper big dock application whose window you don't wish to see, simple as that. Many big proper dock applications have their separate background applets that will keep running even though you quit the actual application from the dock. The list of things that you see in SystemPrefs there mainly consists of those, slightly different to actual big apps. For example, just because I quit the Messages program from my dock doesn't shut down its background applet, therefore I can still get notifications from it.

Comment: @user158589 I don't think that is the reason, see edited question above.

Comment: Have you ever found a way around it? I'm in the exact same situation: I'm mounting a network disk on login, and it shows despite the "Hide" flag.

Comment: @FreeNickname Nope, haven't found a way around it.