# Folder/Finder Startup Items: How not to open window after logon?

Tags: finder, startup

I'm using El Capitan at the moment, but I've had this "problem" for a long time - it's more an inconvenience, really. I have a number of network volumes in my Startup Items because I want them to be re-connected at logon. This works, but always opens a bunch of Finder windows, even though the "Hide" flag in the Preferences is set for these volumes. How can I prevent these windows from re-opening every time I log in - and if this is not possible, is there a trigger or something I could use to automate closing the windows, e. g. using Automator?

---

(I found a related question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233189/why-do-some-login-items-insist-on-displaying-at-startup-despite-being-set-to-h), but it has no answers and is targeted towards general application behaviour - I don't care about other applications at the moment, I'm specifically looking for a solution to the Finder issue.)